# Add/Remove Programs entry missing

Tags: windows, installation, registry, nsis

I have NSI script and compiled installer with following code in it:

```
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "DisplayName" "${NAME}"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "InstallLocation" "$\"$INSTDIR$\""
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "UninstallString " "$\"$INSTDIR\uninstall.exe$\""
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "Publisher" "${COMPANY}"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "URLInfoAbout" "${WEBSITE}"
WriteRegStr HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "DisplayVersion" "3.0.0"
WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "NoModify" "1"
WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "NoRepair" "1"
WriteRegDWORD HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${NAME}" "EstimatedSize" "400"
```

This compiles and creates all keys on install. I can see them in RegEdit. But they are not showing in Add/Remove programs list. No matter what params I delete or add.

I tried creating new Key with exactly same values and it DID display in the list. Permissions are exactly same for both Keys.

**Edit:**

This does not work on Windows Vista and 7, both x64 and x86.
Files are NOT digitally signed.
Path contains space, but it is encapsulated in double brackets.
Key name aka ${NAME} contains two spaces.

Comment: Maybe you could give use some more info. Windows version? x86 or x64?

Comment: @Anders added some additional info.

Comment: Have you rebooted after making the change?

Comment: ..and what have you set RequestExecutionLevel to?

Comment: @BaliC I did, and it does not seem to recognize it still.

Comment: @Anders RequestExecutionLevel admin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was caused by "UninstallString " having an accidental space after the name, so Windows was not recognizing it as a proper entry.

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing a 32b application on a 64b OS, maybe it could help to switch to the 32b part of the registry (the branch that is beneath the `Wow6432Node` before creating the keys ?

```
SetRegView 32
WriteRegStr HKLM [...]
```

Your keys will be visible in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\your_name`

Comment: It is not just x64, also x32 does not do what it should - it does not display it in the list.